# Play 2 - routing to index.html

Tags: scala, angular, playframework-2.0, angular-cli

Is there any way to route GET "/" request in routes file, so it would serve index.html which is in some other directory than default views/index.scala.html? In my case, I want to serve public/main/index.html file (because of using angular2 and angular-cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview#The-Assets-controller):

> To route to a single static file, both the path and file has to be
>   specified:
>
> ```
> GET  /favicon.ico        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="favicon.ico")
> ```

So your case might look like this:

```
GET  /        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="main/index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

in your web server just make all HTML requests serve up index.html

Comment: play is my web server